# Code compiled in Xcode gives an incorrect(?) input vs several other compilers with same inputs

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode10.1

Test inputs and outputs from Xcode (incorrect) and other (web based compilers) are as following:

Input 1: 3 30 0.90 40

Xcode Output 1: 
Acceptable success rate: 0.90
Average attempted sales: 30.00
**Average completed sales: 19.33

Observed success rate: 0.64**
Observed success rate not in acceptable range.
Program ended with exit code: 0

Other Compilers' Output 1(correct):
Acceptable success rate: 0.90
Average attempted sales: 30.00
**Average completed sales: 19.67

Observed success rate: 0.66**
Observed success rate not in acceptable range.

Input 2: 10 100 0.5 1

Xcode Output 2:
Acceptable success rate: 0.50
Average attempted sales: 100.00
**Average completed sales: 29.40

Observed success rate: 0.29**
Observed success rate not in acceptable range.
Program ended with exit code: 0

Other Compilers' Output 1(correct):
Acceptable success rate: 0.50
Average attempted sales: 100.00
**Average completed sales: 28.80

Observed success rate: 0.29**
Observed success rate not in acceptable range.

```
#include <iostream>
#include  <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int iterations, seed;
    double successRate;

    float completedSales = 0, numAttempted;
    int  i, t;
    int seatChoice;

    //Add other variables necessary for your program

    //cout << "Please enter number of iterations to be evaluated" <<endl;
    cin >> iterations; //number of iterations to be evaluated

    //cout << "Please enter number of attempted sales" <<endl;
    cin >> numAttempted; //number of attempted sales

    //cout << "Please enter expected success rate" <<endl;
    cin >> successRate;

    //cout << "Please enter seed for random number generation" <<endl;
    cin >> seed; //seed for random number generation


    //Validate input
    if(iterations <= 0 || numAttempted < 0 || seed < 0 ) {
        cout << "Error. Invalid parameters.";

    }
    else if(successRate < 0 || successRate > 1) {
        cout << "Error. Invalid parameters.";
    }
    else {
        //Set seed and start iterations
        srand(seed);

        //Every iteration of the simulation starts by setting all seats to empty

        for(i = 0; i < iterations; ++i) {

            int availableSeats[30] = {0};

            for(t = 0; t < numAttempted; ++t) {
                seatChoice = (rand() % 30);

                if(availableSeats[seatChoice] == 0) {
                    availableSeats[seatChoice] = 1.0;
                    completedSales++;
                }
            }
        }
        float averageSales = (float) completedSales/iterations;
        float observedSuccessRate = (float) averageSales/numAttempted;

        //Complete final output:
        cout << setprecision(2) <<fixed;
        cout << "Acceptable success rate: "  <<successRate <<endl;
        cout << "Average attempted sales: " <<(double)numAttempted <<endl;
        cout << "Average completed sales: " <<averageSales <<endl;
        cout << "Observed success rate: " <<(float)observedSuccessRate <<endl;

        //Complete if statement to test success rate
        if(observedSuccessRate < successRate) {
            cout << "Observed success rate not in acceptable range." << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Observed success rate is acceptable." << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you clarify why you think Xcode behaves differently?

Comment: I say the code behaves differently because the correct or the expected output is what I should get, but I get a slightly off output. No pattern recognized

Answer (score 1):

Upon re-reading your code, is the "incorrect" behavior simply the different outcome given the same seed? This could be due to a different implementation of `srand` and `rand` between C++ compilers (and standard libraries).

Xcode uses Clang, which defaults to libc++, while your other compilers might use GCC, which uses lib**std**c++. The Microsoft Visual Studio compiler has its own implementation as well.
In general, you **cannot** rely on these implementations being equal.

Your options are to either create your own Pseudo-random number generator (PRNG) or use the built-in [Mersenne twister generator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) `std::mt19937`. That should yield the same results across platforms.

Comment: Agreed.  If the user is complaining about floating point rounding errors (which are large in this case) they should at least use a fixed set of input, rather than leaving it to `rand()` to generate.

Comment: Yes, the "incorrect" output is what Xcode outputs with the same seed. I tried several different web-based and IDE compilers and they all output the expected or "correct" values
Also, thank you for the recommendation @Botje 
I think for this specific application, applying a fix might be an overkill since it will be eventually run in different environment but now I at least know to use more than 1 compiler if my outputs are off after hours of debugging